# PHP & MySQL - Updating Query

Tags: php, html, mysql

I need some help with updating query (html, php, mysql).

So I tried updating mySQL query (signature) connected with HTML. But I often face some problems.

I'd like to update a query (signature) by typing new signature in a form and a button that will submit action and change.

So basically I want to update user's signature when he types new one in a field and submits (presses a button).

If anyone can make a basic system for me so we will look forward successfully making the system.

---

> *Edit:*

Yeah I know that nobody will write the script for me but I'm just out of ideas how could it be made. I'm no professional at all. I apologize for that :)

Anyway, this is the code:

```
<form action="update_signature.php">
        <input type="text" name="txt" />
        <input type="submit" name="insert" value="insert" onclick="insert()" />
        </form>
```

I'm not sure what should I type in `update_signature.php` so I wrote a simple query:

```
<?php 
$myq = mysql_query("UPDATE userSignature FROM users WHERE userSignature='$signature'")
$row=mysql_fetch_array($myq); 
?>      `
```

---

Thanks :)

Comment: *"If anyone can make a basic system for me"* - That isn't how things work on Stack. Try something then come back and post what you had trouble with. We'll be more than happy to help then.

Comment: please put your question here, one can not help you with entire coding.

Answer (score 1):

I like how StackOverflow does not allow comments under 50 reputation...

The HTML code should have a "method", but if you skip it, it just posts as a "get", so not really a problem. In the "onclick" parameter however, you give it a JavaScript function, which does not exist?

The PHP is a mess. First, you need to retrieve the sent value with

```
$something = $_GET['txt'];
```

This puts the value what was left in the input with the name txt into a variable.

Second, the UPDATE syntax is totally different, it's more like

```
"UPDATE table SET column = '$phpvariable', etc... WHERE column2 = '$phpvariable2'"
```

where column is the name of the column in your table, and the query is successful in the lines where the column2 value is equal to the $phpvariable2.

Third, the UPDATE returns with a yes or no (success or not), not with an array.